# ClientId for Razor Helper

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am new to razor so I may have missed something.

What I am trying to do is write a helper to output a HTML fragment this HTML needs several things to happen when the DOM is ready.

Now of course I automatically think of `ClientId` from WebForms to uniquely identify the HTML from the helper output but is there an equivalent in Razor?

Obviously I can just generate something unique when rendered and that isn't a problem I just don't want to be doing something that razor might be providing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided in the end to leave it up to the developer to pass a `ClientInstanceName` to the helper function and that is then used to id the elements inside the helper.

That way they can ensure it's unique on the page they are working on and also know how to access the elements if they need to or apply CSS if needed.